# Filter part of my tree in Gramps

Tags: gramps

I'd like to filter part of my tree, to be able to export only part of my tree for use by other people.

I'd like to filter everything from my grandfather from mothers-side. He has to be the endpoint. I'd like to find all related people and lines connected to him, also the grandchildren from his brother, the great-grandparents from his mother, etc. but nothing from my family of my family-lines.

How can I set up my filter to get this information?

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the version of Gramps that you use, you can simply select your maternal grandfather and then the 'Family Trees' menu, and then 'Export'. This will open a wizard that will guide you easily to the steps of exporting a GEDCOM or other format that can either be ancestors or the descendants of the person you selected.